# How to move a key value to an new array inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

From below object

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 9,
        "email": "abcd@example.com",
    },
    "country": "USA",
    "first_name": "firstName",
    "last_name": "lastName",
}
```

How can we move `first_name` and `last_name` to a new array named `names` and push that into the same object as below

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 9,
        "email": "abcd@example.com",
    },
    "country": "USA",
    "name": [
        {
            "first_name": "firstName",
            "last_name": "lastName",
        }
    ],
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a template of what you want the shape of the new `names` array to look like?

Comment: an array with `first_name` and `last_name` object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `first_name` and `last_name` from the [`rest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) of the properties, then create a new object; [spreading out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the old saved properties, and adding an array with an object with `first_name` and `last_name` properties.

```js
const obj={user:{id:9,email:"abcd@example.com"},country:"USA",first_name:"firstName",last_name:"lastName"};

const { first_name, last_name, ...rest } = obj;

const newObj = {
  ...rest,
  names: [ { first_name, last_name } ]
};

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: tasty solution!

Comment: good solution!! Congratulations !!